# In the same search box search by multiple array object properties

Tags: angular

```
searchTerm: any;

search() {

      this.records = this.records.filter((res: any)=>{
        return res.name.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase());
      });

  }
```

I am making the search term with name which is the property or key in records array. In the same search box I also want to search by age and course.
How can I achieve this.

```
<input type ="text" placeholder="search" (input)=" search();" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expand you're search filter to include your extra criteria:

```
search() {
      this.records = this.records.filter((res: any)=>{
        return (res.name && res.name.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())) || 
        (res.course && res.course.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())) || 
        (res.age && res.age.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())) ;
      });
  }
```

This assumes that both course and age are strings in the records array.

Comment: It breaks if any key is null like in the table if the course of third row is null the code breaks gives the error toLocaleLowerCase of null

Comment: Add some null checks as part of the filter condition, I updated the sample in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using || operator with the same return statement as below :

```
this.records = this.records.filter((res: any)=>{
        return (res.name.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()) || res.age.match(this.searchTerm) || res.course.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()));
});
```

Comment: It breaks if any key is null in the records array, like in the table if the course field of third row is null the code breaks gives the error toLocaleLowerCase of null

Answer (score 0):

You could try to combine the conditions with or, for example like this.

```
search() {

      this.records = this.records.filter((res: any)=>{
        return (res.name.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase() ||
            res.age.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase() ||
            res.course.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase());
      });

  }
```

Comment: It breaks if any key is null like in the table if the course of third row is null the code breaks gives the error toLocaleLowerCase of null

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
search() {
    this.records = this.records.filter((res: any)=>{
      return Object.keys(res).some(item => {
        return item.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
      });
    });
  }
```

This will search whatever property is in the object and check whether it's value matched the criteria. It will stop on the first match